# Eclipse - Only Auto-Indent On Typing

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to have Eclipse only indent new lines when you start typing code? For example, hitting enter brings the text cursor back to the left-hand margin, but starting to type on that line would tab it to the appropriate indentation?

I currently strip trailing whitespace on save, but that's not really the behavior I want.

Comment: By "only", do you mean it's doing it automatically at other times? For what language?

Comment: Is your problem that you don't want lines consisting only of _one or more_ whitespace characters?  If it isn't that, I'm not really sure what you're asking for.

Comment: @nitind For Java, specifically. Currently when I hit enter, it keeps the same tabbing as the previous line, which is annoying when I hit enter twice and the second to last line is still tabbed in (my work is very picky about whitespace).

Comment: @ajb No, not one or more whitespace characters. If you use Eclipse to show all whitespace characters, you can see the indentation on lines that have no code.

Comment: This isn't my image but you can see here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7qzjn.png that there is an indented line right below public class. I only want Eclipse to auto-indent when typing begins.

Comment: I see what you mean, but no, it can't do what you want. The basic auto-indent just mimics the previous line's indentation. You'll have to use the Formatter as directed by Aleksandr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse can automatically add/remove indentation in some cases (one of them is when line is empty). For that you need to enable auto formatting on save action.

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Editor` -> `Save Actions` check both `Perform the selected actions on save` and `Format source code`.

Then make sure that currently used formatter doesn't indent empty lines.

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Code Style` -> `Formatter` click `Edit...` button. In the `Indentation` tab un-check (if checked) `Empty lines` under `Indent` section.

Comment: What I did instead was go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Editor` -> `Save Actions`, checked `Additional Actions` instead, clicked `Configure` and checked `Remove trailing whitespace`. That way I didn't get any other formatting.